# Set style for child widget based on parent widget Property Selector - qt

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets

I wanted to know if the below stylesheet statement is right or not or what is the mistake.. It doesn't change the UI even i set.

```
QWidget#itemScrollAreaWidgetContents PosButton[pressed = "false"] QFrame#baseWidget
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-style: outset;
}

QWidget#itemScrollAreaWidgetContents PosButton[pressed = "true"] QFrame#baseWidget
{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-style: outset;
}
```

My custom widget PosButton has property set

```
Q_PROPERTY(QString pressed READ pressed WRITE setPressed)
```

I change property on mouseclick

```
void PosButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if(rect().contains(event->pos()))
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Emit click";
        emit clicked(this->objectName());
    }

    setPressed("false");
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}

void PosButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    setPressed("true");
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}
```

Also, I tried to set the style sheet. It gets effected, but takes a second to update in UI. ie, I need to keep my widget pressed for a second for the change to appear

```
void PosButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if(rect().contains(event->pos()))
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Emit click";
        emit clicked(this->objectName());
    }

    m_pBaseWidget->setStyleSheet("QFrame#baseWidget {"
                          "border: 1px solid black;"
                          "border-top-width: 0;"
                          "border-left-width: 0;"
                          "border-style: outset;}"
                  );

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}

void PosButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    m_pBaseWidget->setStyleSheet("QFrame#baseWidget {"
                          "border: 2px solid orange;"
                          "border-top-width: 0;"
                          "border-left-width: 0;"
                          "border-style: outset;}"
                  );

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}
```

Comment: Is `PosButton` a `QPushButton` derived class?

Comment: No, it is derived from QWidget

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK `Qt Style Sheets` work for direct `QWidget` subclasses only if you implement the paintEvent like this:

```
void PosButton::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QStyleOption opt;
    opt.init(this);
    QPainter p(this);
    style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_Widget, &opt, &p, this);
}
```

Also what I recommend is using a `bool` type for your `pressed` property like this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(bool pressed READ pressed WRITE setPressed)
```

and reference the property the same way you did already(not sure if it is ok to leave spaces between and after `=`):

```
QWidget#itemScrollAreaWidgetContents PosButton[pressed="false"] QFrame#baseWidget
```

Comment: @luliu: I am setting style for QFrame inside my PosButton. So style sheet set should work, right?

Comment: yes but when you use the property selectors the getters and setters for that property get called. can you please show the `pressed` and `setPressed` member functions? also, as I said, I recommend using `Q_PROPERTY(bool pressed READ pressed WRITE setPressed)` instead of `Q_PROPERTY(String pressed READ pressed WRITE setPressed)`

Comment: I have modified as you said `bool PosButton::pressed()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked" << mPressed;
    return mPressed;
}

void PosButton::setPressed(bool pressed)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked" << pressed;
    mPressed = pressed;
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}`

Comment: No... I removed property related changes. I set border in mouse press and put a timer in mouse release and on timeout I reset the border. `void PosButton::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{ if(rect().contains(event->pos()))
    emit clicked(this->objectName());

    QTimer::singleShot(150, this, SLOT(styleTimeout()));
    return;
}

void PosButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);

    m_pBaseWidget->setStyleSheet("QFrame#baseWidget {border: 2px solid orange; border-top-width: 0; border-left-width: 0; border-style: outset;}");
   return;
}`

Comment: `void PosButton::styleTimeout()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Invoked";

    if (NULL != m_pBaseWidget)
    {
        qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "set style";
        m_pBaseWidget->setStyleSheet("QFrame#baseWidget {"
                              "border: 1px solid black;"
                              "border-top-width: 0;"
                              "border-left-width: 0;"
                              "border-style: outset;}"
                      );
    }

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "Exits";
    return;
}
`